# Windows 11 modifies UEFI boot options after reboot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

Right now I have Windows 11 installed next to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on my computer (same SSD). The thing is that every time I boot Windows, UEFI boot options are modified to the following state:

```
Description:ubuntu
GPT partition GUID:{39909024-C898-42DB-B5C5-4AD704D6D4D7}
Partition number:1
Partition starting sector:2048
Partition ending sector:534527
File path:\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI

Description:Windows Boot Manager
GPT partition GUID:{39909024-C898-42DB-B5C5-4AD704D6D4D7}
Partition number:1
Partition starting sector:2048
Partition ending sector:534527
File path:\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI
```

With the previous two boot options, every time I start my computer the following error is shown just before the GRUB menu:

```
Failed to open \EFI\UBUNTU\XXXSX - Invalid Parameter
Failed to load image \EFI\UBUNTU\XXXSX: Invalid Parameter
start_image() returned Invalid Parameter, falling back to default loader
```

Once the GRUB is shown, I can boot Ubuntu without any issue. On the other hand, I also can boot Windows, but normally I need a second try (the first try the previous error is shown again, followed by the GRUB menu -the pc seems to restart-).

I have been researching for possible solutions and I know that a \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi file is needed instead of \EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI. In order to solve that, I have tried to modify the ubuntu boot entry through [Hasleo EasyUEFI](https://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) with no result (every time I boot Windows and reboot the pc, ubuntu boot options is modified again to \EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI).

Exactly the same happens after executing the following command on terminal:

```
Bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

In this case the ubuntu boot option is overwritten, but after the reboot happens exactly the same.

Every tip is welcome, as my mind is exploding. Thank you very much and sorry for my english...

EDIT: Secure boot and Fast boot are disabled. Also, my computer is an ASUS ROG Zephyrus G15 GA503RM_GA503RM.

Comment: Can you remove Windows and use it in Virtualbox?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi no, VirtualBox is not an option :(

Comment: It usually is better to use shimx64.efi as it works for UEFI Secure boot or with Secure boot off. Grubx64.efi only works with secure boot off. What brand/model system?

Comment: @oldfred ASUS ROG Zephyrus G15 GA503RM_GA503RM

Comment: Your 22.04 should be new enough, but this may show some other settings: ASUS ROG Strix G15 Linux 5.13 stable series or Linux 5.14 req'd. Newer Software components the better. AMD
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=asus-g15-distros&num=1
And https://www.phoronix.com/review/windows-linux-5900hx  Issues are common by vendor across many similar models.